# excel export using 2.color_scale with cell border

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take an excel export from my DataFrames by using conditional formatting with type: `3_color_scale`. The cells are colored, but the cells borders are not.

I want to add cell borders.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'********.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', startrow=1,index=False,header=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet2', startrow=1,index=False,header=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['sheet1']
worksheet1 = writer.sheets['sheet2']

header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'bg_color': '#D7E4BC',
    'border': 1,
    'align' : 'center'})

for col_num, value in enumerate(df1.columns.values):
worksheet.write(0, col_num , value, header_format)
for col_num, value in enumerate(df2.columns.values):
worksheet1.write(0, col_num , value, header_format)

worksheet.conditional_format(xlsxwriter.utility.xl_range(0, 0, len(reduced), len(reduced.columns)), 
{'type': '3_color_scale'})
worksheet1.conditional_format(xlsxwriter.utility.xl_range(0, 0, len(reduced1), 
len(reduced1.columns)), {'type': '3_color_scale'})

writer.save()
```

Sreenshot of cells:
[image: Pic of cells]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough of the program to reproduce the issue but it should work. Here is a simplified example that adds a cell border and a 3 color conditional format:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('conditional_format.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

border_format = workbook.add_format({'border': 1})

data = range(1, 13)
worksheet.write_column(1, 1, data, border_format)

worksheet.conditional_format(1, 1, 12, 1, {'type': '3_color_scale'})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]